# How can add some stuff in Top of a div tag by Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag like this :

```
<div id="movies">

   <p id="p1">Hi my friend....</p>
   <p id="p2">this is the best...</p> 

</div>
```

and i write a script which call a method and get us some Data(in Json) format and then append these data to div tag by id=movie, and my new data added under the p tag by id=p2, but i want its added the data above p tag by id=p1, How i can do it?
my script :

```
     function () {
                    var objects = [];
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./WebForm1.aspx/GetUnCheckNotification",
                    data: {},
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:
                    function (response) {
                                var htm = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                                        htm.push("" + response.d[i].TITLE + "" + response.d[i].DESC + "");


                                    };
                                    $("#movies").append(htm.join('<div></div><br/>'));
                                },

                        });


                    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#movies").prepend(htm.join('<div></div><br/>'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Or

```
$("#movies #p1").before(htm.join('<div></div><br/>'));
```

https://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: `$("#movies p:first").before(htm.join('<div></div><br/>'));` this would be better. yet first one is the way to go.